# Template function to return containers of unrelated types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-templates, stdset

I have several containers of unrelated types. I would like to write a templated function to process input values and insert them into the corresponding containers. This is my best try so far:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <set>

struct A {
  // Must have operator< or std::less to insert into a std::set
  // Probably a bad idea to do it by memory address
  bool operator<(A const& other) const { return this < &other; }
};
struct B {
  bool operator<(B const& other) const { return this < &other; }
};
struct C {
  bool operator<(C const& other) const { return this < &other; }
};

std::set<A> aSet; 
std::set<B> bSet;
std::set<C> cSet;

template 
<typename T> 
std::set<T>& getSet();

template 
<> 
std::set<A>& getSet<A>() { return aSet; }

template 
<> 
std::set<B>& getSet<B>() { return bSet; }

template 
<> 
std::set<C>& getSet<C>() { return cSet; }

template 
<typename T> 
void process(T const& value) { 
  std::set<T>& specializedSet(getSet<T>());
  specializedSet.insert(value); 
}

int main() 
{ 
  // do stuff
  process(A()); process(A()); process(A());
  process(B()); process(B());
  process(C());

  std::cout<<"Set has "<<getSet<A>().size()<<" element(s)\n"
           <<"Set has "<<getSet<B>().size()<<" element(s)\n"
           <<"Set has "<<getSet<C>().size()<<" element(s)"<<std::endl;
}
```

It produces the expected output:

```
Set has 3 element(s)
Set has 2 element(s)
Set has 1 element(s)
```

I would strongly prefer not to have to specialize `getSet()` for every type (I actually have 10), though it's worth it to be able to templatize `process()`. Ideally I wouldn't even need to declare separate containers `aSet`, `bSet`, etc. I could make all these types pointers if that's helpful, though I'd like to stay away from `set::set<void*>` or similar opaque coding if possible. If this is a duplicate, I apologize, it's a bit tricky to search for.

Comment: Did you try storing all your sets in a `std::tuple`, and having your `getSet()` become a laughably trivial wrapper around `std::get`? The shown code appears to be simply reinventing this wheel.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I see that in C++14 I could make `std::tuple<std::set<A>, std::set<B>, std::set<C>> sets` and then use type-based access to have `template <typename T> std::set<T>& getSet() { return std::get<T>(sets); }`, is that what you're thinking? I agree, that's much nicer than what I have now. I can't use C++14 for this, but I I could reimplement `std::get<T>`. Thanks, I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::set<T>& getSet()
{
    static std::set<T> s;
    return s;
}
```

This will create a new `std::set` for the type `T`, the first time `getSet<T>()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

With C++14, you might use template variable:

```
template <typename T>
std::set<T> mySet{};
```

Previously, you might wrap it in template function:

```
template <typename T>
std::set<T>& getSet() { static std::set<T> instance; return instance; }
```